# Massive sql delete query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, sql-delete

I have to delete a lot of data based on id value. Which one is the fastest :

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id = '10' OR id = '20' OR id = '43' OR id = '54' .......
```

or

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id = '10'; DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id = '20'; ........
```

If you have an another solution, don't hesitate to tell me.

(the id here is not primary key or indexed, is a foreignkey because it references a word and I can have multiple entry for one word in this database)

I use MySQL but I want that my query can be applied on other RDBMS

Comment: The first one is better, because there will be less logging-related work to do by database engine.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: thanks because the two way take very too much time. So hard to measure it. What do you think about Sachin example ? I use MySQL but I want my query to be applied on other RDBMS too

Comment: quite like the question title :). will add to the curiosity of whats massive inside.

Comment: massive as the chinese dictionnary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is faster but I would like to use `IN` operator like this for more `readability` though with same performance

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id in ('10','20','30',...)
```

Comment: Don't forget the inverted commas. It seems the `id`'s data type is text/nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

**First** one should be **faster**,

Having one statement is better than having set of statements in terms of **Query Optimizer** output.

Comment: The second solution does not necessarily mean there are multiple *transactions*. A transaction can span more than one statement. But I do agree that a single *statement* is most probably faster than multiple statements.

Comment: judging by your reputation, you should be aware that SQL can run a statement without transactions. i'm pretty sure of that on MS SQL Server not only MySQL !

Comment: No you can not, not even on SQL Server. You might have an implicit transaction that is automatically maintained by the engine, but it's impossible to run a SQL statement *without* a transaction (again with the MySQL exception of not supporting transactions at all)